# Incorrect Unicode property near index

Tags: android, regex

I'm trying to use my method from java backend in android app (the problem might be that the backend is using JAVA 1.7, and the android app JAVA 1.6). The method is:

```
public static boolean isAlphabetCharacter(String letter) {
    String pattern = "\\A\\pL+\\z";
    return letter.matches(pattern);
}
```

It crashes with: `Incorrect Unicode property near index ...`

Comment: Try `\p{L}` instead of `\pL`

Comment: Make it an answer please :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should try `\p{L}` instead of `\pL` :)

Answer (score 1):

It is Weird. When developing Android app, i encounter this problem.

1. Unit test is passed when i use `Regex("[\\pP\\pZ]")`, but Android app encounter `java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Incorrect Unicode property`
2. then i change to `Regex("[\\p{P}\\p{Z}]")`, both unit test and android app is ok.

I dont know why....